Identity in ASP.NET Core 6 MVC
I am working on an ASP.NET Core MVC 6 application that uses ASP.NET Core identity and I am facing an issue trying to figure out how to work with the UserManager class.
But UserManager always has null value, I do not know why?
Is ASP.NET Core 6 does not have identity in controllers? and identity scaffolded items are in Razor pages?
But I do not want to use Razor pages
This is Code:
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationSignInManager _signInManager;
    private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;

    public BaseController(ApplicationUserManager userManager, ApplicationSignInManager signInManager)
    {
        UserManager = userManager;
        SignInManager = signInManager;
    }

    public ApplicationSignInManager SignInManager
    {
       get
       {
           return _signInManager;
       }
       private set
       {
          _signInManager = value;
       }
   }

   public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
   {
       get
       {
             return _userManager;
       }
       private set
       {
             _userManager = value;
       }
  }


  [HttpPost]
  [AllowAnonymous]
  [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
  public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterVM model)
  {
      if (ModelState.IsValid)
      {
          var user = new User
          {
              UserName = model.Email,
              Email = model.Email,
              EmailConfirmed = true
          };

          var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

          if (result.Succeeded)
          {
              await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
              return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
          }
          foreach (var error in result.Errors)
          {
              ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
          }
      }

    
      return View(model);
  }
}

ApplicationUserManager class Code:
public sealed class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<IdentityUser>
{}


why you'r extending UserManager?  are you need custom methods?

Is that the reason to get null value in UserManager?

probably yes , if you want extend UserManager use this approach

Why this ApplicationUserManger doesn't inject as noraml?

@Qiang Fu, I think I miss something in confiuration as it is first time I work with Core -
Can we complete in chat please?

@MrMustafa022 Sorry I was busy. I write an answer of common usage may be help.

If you start from the MVC template with "individual" authentication, just inject "UserManager" and "SignInManager" like following:
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;

        public AccountController(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager,SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager)
        {
            this._userManager = userManager;
            this._signInManager = signInManager;
        }

        public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterVM model)
        {
            ...
            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            ...
                await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
        }

If you want to implement custom Manager , then it will be like:
    public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<IdentityUser>
    {
        public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<IdentityUser> store, IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor, IPasswordHasher<IdentityUser> passwordHasher, IEnumerable<IUserValidator<IdentityUser>> userValidators, IEnumerable<IPasswordValidator<IdentityUser>> passwordValidators, ILookupNormalizer keyNormalizer, IdentityErrorDescriber errors, IServiceProvider services, ILogger<UserManager<IdentityUser>> logger) : base(store, optionsAccessor, passwordHasher, userValidators, passwordValidators, keyNormalizer, errors, services, logger)
        {
        }
    }
    public class ApplicationSignInManager : SignInManager<IdentityUser>
    {
        public ApplicationSignInManager(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager, IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor, IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<IdentityUser> claimsFactory, IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor, ILogger<SignInManager<IdentityUser>> logger, IAuthenticationSchemeProvider schemes, IUserConfirmation<IdentityUser> confirmation) : base(userManager, contextAccessor, claimsFactory, optionsAccessor, logger, schemes, confirmation)
        {
        }
    }

program.cs
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
    .AddUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>()
    .AddSignInManager<ApplicationSignInManager>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

Controller
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ApplicationUserManager _userManager;
        private readonly ApplicationSignInManager  _signInManager;

        public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager userManager, ApplicationSignInManager signInManager)
        {
            this._userManager = userManager;
            this._signInManager = signInManager;
        }

